# Least expensive way to build a forest in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, 3d, terrain

I'm a programmer with some experience in Unity. My objective is to make a game (or maybe just a virtual space you can walk around in First Person perspective) featuring a forest and to make it look as good as I can (probably using HDRP to try and exploit all its potential) through the use of lighting and shaders. I will be using assets from the Asset Store to fill my scene.

I have a little bit of experience with the official Unity terrain tools but I have available the Gaia asset, which I have never used but have heard plenty of good things about it. What would be the advantages of using the Gaia terrain generator over Unity official tools?

I think both Unity Terrain Generator as well as Gaia have the ability to instantiate trees, maybe Gaia has more included assets to use and fill the environment? If so, would this assets be part of the terrain or would they be considered GameObjects? All of this I ask with optimization in mind (culling, LODs).

Anyway, I'd appreciate any tips for making (and optimizing) this sort of environment, as well as advice regarding what kind of Terrain tools to use to make it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: why just dont use unity standard way?

Comment: I'm asking for advice from all those with experience building terrains. I guess the standard way will work but surely Gaia may prove benefitial. I don't know, that's why I asked.

Comment: when unity makes something standard it means they chose most standard an low weight for this. if you can introduce something better, maybe it can be a good field of research. just implement what works right for you and check it works fine in your goal devices beside your other features.

Comment: This looks just on this edge of a "which technology should I use?" question, which is off-topic here. Can you tell us more about how you've tried using the Unity built-in / Gaia tools so far? Is there a specific problem you've encountered with one or the other that we can help you solve? Note that game developers typically won't know the "best" or "least expensive" way to do anything — optimality proofs are not part of our process — all we know are ways that were "good enough" for our needs at the time. So, in what way is what you have tried "not good enough" and how can we help improve it?

Comment: I have no experience with Gaia, only with the Unity standard terrain, and it suited my needs just fine. I think using Gaia might prove benefitial but I'm just asking for someone with experience on both (if it's for making forested areas even better) to give me their thoughts. I'm unexperienced in this site and maybe it should have been posted in the off-topic section, my apologies.